# Does odds has different meaning?

Tags: meaning

As I know, odds are a numerical expression. But when come to this sentences, does it sounds other meanings ?

> If you’re working on a Flutter app, odds are you’re going to need to
>   implement login.

I get this sentences from [Flutter Login Tutorial with “flutter_bloc”](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*odds* is the probability that something will or will not happen in the future.

> If you’re working on a Flutter app, **you may need** to implement login.
>
> If you’re working on a Flutter app, **it's likely** you’re going to need to implement login.
>
> If you’re working on a Flutter app, **there's a probability that** you’re going to need to implement login.
>
> If you’re working on a Flutter app, **there's a good chance that** you’re going to need to implement login.

"what are the odds?" is a widely popular question.

[image: poster with the title "what are your odds"]

I assume it should have been "**the** odds are". I am not certain, though.

Comment: I think it is *the odds are* with *the* omitted

Comment: thanks, it clear for me now.

Answer (score 1):

"Odds are" is a phrase meaning "it is likely that". You can also have "the odds are against it" (meaning it's unlikely), "don't go against the odds" and so on.

"Odds" doesn't always imply an exact number and may even be based on pure guesswork.

Comment: thanks, it clear for me now.